# Combination of matrix-vector multiplication with coefficient-wise product in eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to condense a bit of code using functions in Eigen, specifically the ones that allow you to do coefficient-wise products of arrays, but am perhaps using them incorrectly. The basic idea is contained in this expanded for loop:

```
  for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < nlocal; i++)
    {
      for (int qp = 0; qp < nVolQuad; qp++)
        qNewPtr[i] += 
          volQuad.weights(qp)*bigStoredVolMatrices[dir](i,qp)*alpha(dir,qp)*fAtQuad(qp);
    }
  }
```

which I am trying to condense to:

```
  for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
  {  
    resultVectorDir[dir].noalias() = bigStoredVolMatrices[dir]*
      (volQuad.weights.array()*fAtQuad.array()*alpha.row(dir).array()).matrix();  
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nlocal; i++)
  {
    for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
      qNewPtr[i] += resultVectorDir[dir](i);
  }
```

or without switching between array and matrix, using something like:

```
  for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
  {  
    resultVectorDir[dir].noalias() = bigStoredVolMatrices[dir]*
      (volQuad.weights.cwiseProduct(fAtQuad.cwiseProduct(alpha.row(dir))));  
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nlocal; i++)
  {
    for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
      qNewPtr[i] += resultVectorDir[dir](i);
  }
```

The strange thing to me is sometimes this works. The code sometimes produces the desired output, but then also sometimes produces NaNs. I thought I might need to explicitly zero out the resultVectorDir in the condensed version, but that didn't fix the issue. I figured there was maybe just something subtle about performing this order of operations? Any assistance which can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

As an addendum to this question, I have attacked this issue with good old fashioned print statements and have found that I must not be using the coefficient wise product of arrays function correctly. For example, in a situation where nVolQuad = 9, I ran this segment of code:

```
  for (int dir = 0;  dir < NDIM; dir++)
  {
    tempArray = volQuad.weights.cwiseProduct(fAtQuad.cwiseProduct(alpha.row(dir)));
    for (int qp = 0; qp < nVolQuad; qp++)
    {
      std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << tempArray(qp) << " "; 
      std::cout << volQuad.weights(qp)*alpha(dir,qp)*fAtQuad(qp) << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
```

A chunk of the output looks like this:

-2.23064e-05 -2.23064e-05

1.49458e-154 -3.56902e-05

6.94729e-310 -2.23064e-05

-2.68156e+154 -2.0672e-05

6.94729e-310 -3.30752e-05

6.94729e-310 -2.0672e-05

2.13645e-314 -2.99114e-06

6.94729e-310 -4.78582e-06

6.94729e-310 -2.99114e-06

Other segments of the output are similar. The first entry is correct, but the other 8 entries of the tempArray are nonsense. tempArray is initialized to 0.0 before the loop, so I am at a bit of a loss. I'll keep digging through the documentation of Eigen to make sure I am not doing something exceedingly stupid in my use of this function.

Comment: *I thought I might need to explicitly zero out the resultVectorDir in the condensed version* -- All variables / arrays should be initialized to a known value before you use them (or some code sets the initial value), regardless of what library you're using.  What is `qNewPtr`, and is `qNewPtr[i]` initialized before applying `+=` to it?

Comment: Yep! qNew (and the pointer to qNew) is set to 0 before the loop. That was a poor choice of words on my part. What I meant was, I thought that was the error at first that I was not giving resultVectorDir an initial value. When I fixed that, it did not fix my issue sadly.

Comment: Using `operator=` sets the values of `resultVectorDir`. Can you supply the definitions of all the variables, or better yet a [mcve]?

Comment: Your comment made me go back and look at how the data was initialized. Turns out it was a silly mistake on my part, because volQuad.weights and fAtQuad were both initialized with Eigen::VectorXd which defaults to column vectors, but alpha.row(dir) is a row vector. Thus, why the coefficient-wise product function was giving me garbled results for every entry that wasn't the first. Thanks!

Comment: Running your code (without `-DNDEBUG`) would have told you as much when an assertion failed, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The key error is in the assumption that you can immediately go from the expanded loop to the coefficient wise product, when the expanded loop is accessing data that's different sizes. Here:

```
volQuad.weights.cwiseProduct(fAtQuad.cwiseProduct(alpha.row(dir)))
```

Since volQuad.weights and fAtQuad are initialized with Eigen::VectorXd, they are column vectors, but by using alpha.row(dir), that particular data structure is a row vector. Thus, the coefficient wise product doesn't make sense and you're only going to get the first entry correct. This can be fixed easily by changing the syntax to:

```
volQuad.weights.cwiseProduct(fAtQuad.cwiseProduct(alpha.row(dir).transpose()))
```